# Extract Elements From Different Websites

Tags: html, excel, vba

Im trying to extract different elements from different websites using their own individual VBA macros. I'm using XMLHTTP.

However I can't seem to make it work. I have looked into the codes as shown below and they all look so different that I dont know what to apply to extract what I want based on what I have researched so far.

Site #1 using "View page source"
Extract 5,061

```
<p class="card-text">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                         <div class="col-md-3 px-1">
                              <p class="text-center mt-4 py-0 my-0"><a class="text-white" href="https://www.bestplaces.net/people/city/tennessee/dunlap"><u>Population</u></a></p>
                              <p class="text-center py-0 my-0" style="font-size:30px;">5,061</p>
```

Site #2 from the XML file of the website
Extract 102196

```
<response>
<results>
<result>
<zpid>154607080</zpid>
<links>
<homedetails>
https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/2912-W-1st-St-APT-1-Jacksonville-FL-32254/154607080_zpid/
</homedetails>
<graphsanddata>
http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/2912-W-1st-St-APT-1-Jacksonville-FL-32254/154607080_zpid/#charts-and-data
</graphsanddata>
<mapthishome>http://www.zillow.com/homes/154607080_zpid/</mapthishome>
<comparables>http://www.zillow.com/homes/comps/154607080_zpid/</comparables>
</links>
<address>
<street>2912 W 1st St APT 1</street>
<zipcode>32254</zipcode>
<city>Jacksonville</city>
<state>FL</state>
<latitude>30.339737</latitude>
<longitude>-81.716677</longitude>
</address>
<zestimate>
<amount currency="USD">102196</amount>
```

Site #3 using "View page source"
Extract $76,869

```
<div class="Text__TextBase-sc-1cait9d-0-div Text__TextContainerBase-sc-1cait9d-1 hlvKRM">$76,869</div>
```

This is how a part of my codes looks like

```
With Http
    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .send
    Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

On Error Resume Next
add = Html.querySelector("zestimate").getAttribute("amount")
```

I truly appreciate anyone showing me the correct way to extract these information.

Comment: I have tried other types of approaches, they are still giving me errors. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You have posted a piece of generic code which cannot be used as a passepartout. Each case has its own characteristics and the code needs to be modified accordingly. The XML and the HTML codes you've posted are not helping either. Please provide links and describe what exactly you are trying to achieve and what you've been able to do so far.

Comment: Hi @StavrosJon, thank you for looking into this. An answer was provided by Skin and it worked. ```If objXml.LoadXML(objHttp.responseText) Then
        Debug.Print objXml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("response/results/result/zestimate/amount").Text
    End If```